# want to show a dialog message in jQuery mobile when it's first loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

In jQuery mobile, I want to show a dialog message in my homepage (`index.html`) when this page is first loaded. However, if the user navigates to different pages of my site and comes back to my `index.html`, I don't want to show show the dialog.

I am thinking about using `pageshow` or `pagebeforeshow` method and checking `prevPage` object. Is there any other good way to do it?

Comment: @David That's another option, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **pageinit** event, It will trigger only once. Can't be easier then this.

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/e9RcT/

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#index', function(){       
    alert('This event will trigger only once!');
});
```

To test it go to second page and then go back.

Comment: The only issue with this approach is it assumes the page will remain cached in the DOM. If `#index` gets flushed, I am pretty sure `pageinit` gets fired again when the page is re-loaded. If this is he case, you will need to employ some type of local storage or cookie to maintain the state of having shown the message.

Comment: @Gajotres It's a very quick solution. I am also considering andleer's comment. In that case, local storage will be a good solution. Thank you!

Comment: In case you also want to incorporate andleer solution take a look at my other article: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600 , there you will an example of localstorage usage.

Answer (score 2):

Loading on the DOM will ensure whatever you want to take place only happens on the first page initialization:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // do stuff here
});
```

source: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html

Comment: Read before you post something. document ready should NOT be used with jQuery Mobile. And regarding pageinit: To execute code whenever a new page is loaded and created, you can bind to the pageinit event. This event is explained in detail at the bottom of this page.

Comment: It's "recommended" NOT enforced as a requirement to using jQuery Mobile. But I see that your answer is also relative. Thanks Gajo

Comment: @Gajotres If the `document.ready` event handler is only found on the `index.html` page (outside of the `<div data-role="page">` element) then this will work as desired. The `document.ready` event handler will only fire if the user directly loads or refreshes the `index.html` page. If the user navigates to the `index.html` page after landing on a different page, the event handler will not fire. It seems like this is one case where `document.ready` is actually better than `pageinit` or any other jQuery Mobile event.